# mitigating vicious mutually recursive types (Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite)

Tags: typescript, circular-reference, mapped-types

I recently learned more about advanced typescript types, and I'm trying to apply what I've learned to accurately type a mechanism we use to specify includes in our REST API.

When GET-ing an entity, any of a set of available includes can be passed. Some of those includes have their *own* available includes, and so on recursively.

Previously, these were typed simply as:

```js
interface IncludeParam {
  param: string
  include?: IncludeParam[]
}
```

Here's the fancier definition I've come up with, along with some example uses:

```js
type IncludeParam<
  Params extends string = string,
  NestedIncludes extends { [param in Params]?: IncludeParam } = { [param in Params]: IncludeParam },
> = {
  [Param in Params]: {
    param: Param
    include?: NestedIncludes[Param] extends IncludeParam ? NestedIncludes[Param][] : never[]
  }
}[Params]

type UserInclude = IncludeParam<'posts' | 'payment' | 'awards', {
  posts: PostInclude
  payment: PaymentInclude
}>

type PostInclude = IncludeParam<'user' | 'images', {
  user: UserInclude
}>

type PaymentInclude = IncludeParam<'provider', {}>

const validUserIncludes: UserInclude[] = [
  { param: 'payment', include: [{ param: 'provider' }] },
  { param: 'posts', include: [{ param: 'images' }] },
  { param: 'awards' },
]

const invalidUserIncludes: UserInclude[] = [
  // @ts-expect-error
  { param: 'foo' },
  // @ts-expect-error
  { param: 'posts', include: [{ param: 'provider' }]},
  // @ts-expect-error
  { param: 'awards', include: [{ param: 'foo' }] },
  // @ts-expect-error
  {
    param: 'posts',
    include: [
      { param: 'images' },
      { param: 'user', include: [{ param: 'foo' }] }
    ]
  },
]
```

Observe that there's a cycle `UserInclude` -> `posts` -> `PostInclude` -> `user` -> `UserInclude`.

In [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwDYFcAmEAKBDATtgWwB4AoKKHfAgZyggA9gI41brhcBLOAcygF4o7LrwA0ZKADkI7CGnjJ0Muo2asoAbygBtMHkJRuFfTQC6AfgBcsRKgyUDAXwGadeqobjGq1U9YV2WCZQjuIAfC4aEtoOBJ7ehL7WUeTk7oTWsRLk3IoYVlIyTPK2StQxJqYqTCy0AUqxUOaFsiV5MhVUptpV1nAQAG4QuD0SjiSOnYmmJCSgkFAAqtTD9Rgua0FURADkYAD27NQ7UAA+UHvYIATMwCfnO9gA7nisO6KaEgdHmYfAm18rjc4MBMkDbgDHGFZvNoJg-psNqV7CZdigVrh7hdOARsDwZO9PuR0cNrMtVsiIBNoXNwHDwSDEYJNrFdmBcPsBpwMJiPhoobMEPs4OwoANsEhueTcJsyRjNj0XNoJFp0gRrJdrrdCblAtZtKqTBr2ZzucMTo4qqEVVA1ca-scPrqlPrDVQNTi8QSQlbxOQ3RkLs9XscQuIZiQhSLgJ5xZK0NLNtQ5RT2orBMr-bajRdvsBQ9byAB6ItQAAC+YAtAxIAhgNXcBzcDa7RcAGb7fYWv1QEvlqs1iB1htNls5vYOnWU13Z925jlcnkW0yF3ulivUav0Wv14ajrOtx4vXBvJ3TnQB9XtzvLsMSPsbrc7kf7Zv+7KzwMTo7vD-OjD6h+B7jp6+IFj2qSuIeJK8p47QzoeHZdj6IQfjM5DWqYQA), the `UserInclude` definition results in the error:

> Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

In my typescript version (4.6.4), there is no such error, but nested includes aren't type checked as expected, as soon as a type has a cycle.

Is there any way I can refine my definition to allow the circularity, or to gracefully relax restrictions for a nested include only in the case where that one include type forms a cycle?

Comment: You have a circular reference `UserInclude -> PostInclude -> UserInclude` which can have any finite or infinite depth, you may write such an object

Comment: @Dimava Sorry yes I'm aware of where my cycle is. I'm asking what I can do about it. I want to be able to include a post from a user, or a user from a post, each potentially with their own nested includes.